# Why ArrayList.toArray method pass an array parameter instead of an array class parameter？

Tags: java

Here I have a ArrayList `List<String> list` and I want to convert it to an array with `String[]`

So I check the `ArrayList` API, got a method `toArray(T[] a)`, the only one with generic type.

I wonder know why doesn't `ArrayList` have a method like this below?

```
public <T> T[] toArray(Class<T[]> type) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, type);
}
```

So I just call it `list.toArray(String[].class)` without crearte a new array. It work I try it, and I think it's simpler.

Of course maybe I didn't get the author's ideas about `ArrayList.toArray`.

So I would like to ask everyone to point out my mistake or share me about the advantages of the original method `toArray(T[] a)`. Thank you! :)

Comment: Because `Class<T[]>` would be array (that is a Java array is its' own type) and after type erasure, `T[]` would be `Object[]`. Why do you want a `String[]` from a `List<String>` anyway?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Sorry i didn't see your reply just now. it is my mistake. And I try what I mention in my question. It works, I get a result with type `String[]` not `Object[]`. Is there no type erasure here? I confuesed

Comment: @Elliott Frisch About why I want a `String[]` from a `List<String>`, just because I want to call a third-party api and it need a `Array` not a `List`. So I need convert it. That's all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the method pre-dates *generics*.

Back in Java 1.2 when the method was created, it was declared as:

```
public Object[] toArray(Object[] a)
```

The caller could then create the correct type of array, e.g. `String[]`, and cast the return value. If the array was adequately size, no reflection would be needed to re-size the array, so it was better for performance.

The performance landscape of Java has changed immensely since then, so some of the performance considerations that was done with the design might seem unnecessary these days.

The designers also added that weird C-like quirk of `null`'ing the element immediately after the last element from the list if the array is oversized. I doubt that that would happen if the method was designed these days.

When *generics* was added in Java 5, some classes were changed to be generic, such as all the Collection classes, and all the existing methods were changed as much as possible to accommodate that. Some methods could be changed for backwards compatibility, e.g. `Map.get(Object key)` wasn't changed to `Map.get(K key)` since it was previously valid to call `get()` with an object that couldn't be in the map.

The `toArray` method was changed, since it remained fully backwards compatible even with the change:

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I learned a lot. So maybe the method `toArray(Class<T[]> type)` is also feasible. And the `toArray` with parameter `(T[] a)` is only because the history. Thanks!

Comment: But I try it, it works. I am confuesd. I create a class named `ZXList` and I copy from `ArrayList` code into `ZXList`, add a new method `toArray(Class<T[]> type)` which I mention in my question. I call the new method like `list.toArray(String[].class)`. It works indeed. Why you say is not feasible. Where am i wrong? Please help me point out the error. Thanks!

Comment: Is it for the same reason (backward compatibility) that `toArray()` returns `Object[]`, when in fact it is possible to returns `E[]`, with `E` is the type of the collection item?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa The no-arg `toArray()` cannot return `E[]` because *type-erasure* means that it doesn't know what `E` is.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are referring to `java.util.ArrayList.class`. It does in-fact have a function

Internally, the function is doing the same thing you are doing. What is wrong in this?

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        if (a.length < size)
            // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
            return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
        System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
        if (a.length > size)
            a[size] = null;
        return a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I noticed this method, there is nothing wrong with this method, but I don't want create a new array and call the method. I wonder know why   there is not a method with `Class<T[]> type` parameter, it's more simpler.

Comment: @zhouxin Because the designers haven't added that overload (yet). They probably never will, as it's fairly redundant with the existing method. But if you really want it, you should file an enhancement request to get it added. If enough people want it, it may happen.

Comment: There are many different ways for it. At constant efforts to be General Purpose Language, Java and the community will always strive to provide methods and ways to be general. I believe this is essential and as long as there is a way to achieve this, i believe your question is elegant but implementable but there's no point in it.

Comment: I got it. @ Andreas Thanks ! : )